# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError when execute Scala runnable jar

Tags: scala, apache-spark, java-native-interface

I have a quite straight-forward Scala program is to get hash value of strings extracted from database. The hash function I have to use is cityhash64withseed produced by Google which has only  C++ implementation. So my solution is to build one C++ libCityhashNative.so called by my Scala spark program via JNI.
This .so will return me hash value of the string I passed into.

1. I packed libCityhashNative.so in Runnable jar tdw_spark-1.0-all.jar.
2. Extract it from jar and write it to temporary path of server.
3. Load it by `System.load(tmp.getAbsolutePath())`.

My code is like this:

```
    package com.tencent.omg.tasks.jni
    class  CityhashNative {
    // --- Native methods
    @native def intMethod(n: Int): Int
    @native def getCityHash64(strToHash: String, length: Int, ddwSeed: Int): Int
    }

    object CityhashNative {
        val path="/video/libCityhashNative.so"
        val prefix = "libCityhashNative"
        val suffix = ".so"

        //create tmp file on server with file prefix and suffix
        val tmp = File.createTempFile(prefix, suffix)

        var buff = new Array[Byte](1024)
        val len : Int = 0
        val out = new FileOutputStream(tmp)
        //load libCityhashNative.so from Jar to inputStream
        val in = getClass.getResourceAsStream(path)
        val reader = new BufferedInputStream(in)

        //write libCityhashNative.so to server location tmp via outputStream
        while(reader.read(buff)>0){
          out.write(buff)
          buff = new Array[Byte](1024)
        }

        System.load(tmp.getAbsolutePath())
        val chn = new CityhashNative
        val hashValue = chn.getCityHash64("XXXX", 9, 5)
}
```

The thing wired is when i run the jar by

```
spark-submit --master local  --class com.tencent.omg.tasks.jni.CityhashNative tdw_spark-1.0-all.jar
```

i will get below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.tencent.omg.tasks.jni.CityhashNative.getCityHash64(Ljava/lang/String;II)I
    at com.tencent.omg.tasks.jni.CityhashNative.getCityHash64(Native Method)
    at com.tencent.omg.tasks.jni.CityhashNative$.main(CityhashNative.scala:86)
    at com.tencent.omg.tasks.jni.CityhashNative.main(CityhashNative.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:744)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

But if I run by

```
scala -cp . CityhashNative
```

it works!!!

So i am a little confused where i did wrong when generate the jar. or the reason is just the .so is not loaded successfully?

Any advice will be very appreciated.

PS: I am sure that libCityhashNative.so is successfully extracted from jar and written to server temp path.

Comment: You should be able to see that the problem lies somewhere in the implementation of `com.tencent.omg.tasks.jni.CityhashNative.getCityHash64` and none of us here have any idea of what this thing is.

Comment: Hi Sorry for misleading you, actually com.tencent.omg.tasks.jni.CityhashNative.getCityHash64 is the native funcation i defined, I haved updated the code and kindly check please. thanks